# Modify all JavaScript user-defined functions

Tags: javascript

I need to modify all user-defined functions in a JS code automatically, for example:

```
    <script>
       function b(m, n) {
           return m + n;
       }
       function a() {
           return b(3, 4);
       }
       function c(){
           alert(a());
       }
    </script>
```

I want to change them to:

```
    <script>
       function b(m, n) {
           return m + n;
           alert('New-Line');
       }
       function a() {
           return b(3, 4);
           alert('New-Line');
       }
       function c(){
           alert(a());
           alert('New-Line');
       }
    </script>
```

I want to add a line of code at the end of each function's body. Can a peace of JS code accomplish this automatically? I do not want to use a third-party tool, but a script in other programming language like Python would be a good manner for my purpose.
Meantime, I wanted to know if JS built-in functions are changeable? I mean, can I modify them such as a user-defined function?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The change you want to make will have no effect when the added line comes after a `return` statement. Those `alert()` calls will never be made.

Comment: You can change the function that the names a, b, c are bound to - but you cannot change the definition of an already-existing function.  What you could do is design your functions so that they are implemented by calling a second function through a closure - then when you change the value of the closure, the implementation of the function will change.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, you are right! My example is wrong and added lines wont be executed. However, this is not the matter I will add the new line in the right position. I am looking for the approach currently.

Comment: If you're trying to do this to a body of *source* code, the only way to do it reliably is to use a JavaScript parser (written in any language)  and augment the functions that way. That would not be very easy. What is it that you're really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Yes, that is all that I want to do. But, I want to find the fastest as well as easiest manner.

Comment: There is no "easy" way to do this. It's a distinctly hard problem to reliably modify source code in a programming language.

Comment: You are faced with some problem, and at some point you decided "I will solve the problem by adding code to all functions." What I am saying is that that was the wrong decision. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Actually, I need a custom JS call/stack tracer. Since I do not want to use third-party tools, I guess this is the only manner. Do you have any other suggestion?